# Pandas dataFrame append AND add new column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to append data frames together when I "find" them in a for loop, as well as add additional columns.

By this I mean:

I have an existing data frame X

```
a    b   c
1    2   3
5    6   7
9    10  11
```

I have a for loop which I "find" certain rows which meet conditional arguments. I then want to add these rows to an empty frame, with additional columns.so new data frame Y would be:

```
a   b   c  next
5   6   7   8
```

where next is the new column added. So far I have tried to add in the following way:

```
allInfo = pd.DataFrame(columns=[list(X), "next"])
allInfo = allInfo.append([a[a.apply(lambda x:someConditional,axis=1)], valueNext],ignore_index=True)
```

But this does not work. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you provide your actual DataFrame and the operation you're performing, I'm guessing there's a pretty simple chained operation. Tough to give a great answer with this lack of detail though.

Comment: I understand, but im working with very large data frames in both length and width. The code provided is the code im using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best is create list of `DataFrames` in loop and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them together with original `df`.

```
final = pd.concat([df, df1, df2, df3,...])
```

But better is avoid all loops in pandas, because slow.

```
df1 = df[df.a == 5].copy()
df1['next'] = 8
print (df1)
   a  b  c  next
1  5  6  7     8

df2 = df[df.a == 1].copy()
df2['next'] = 10
print (df2)
   a  b  c  next
0  1  2  3    10

dfs = [df, df1, df2]
final = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print (final)

   a   b   c  next
0  1   2   3   NaN
1  5   6   7   NaN
2  9  10  11   NaN
3  5   6   7   8.0
4  1   2   3  10.0
```

Comment: Thanks! this is great. Im working in a loop so will have to modify slightly but is a great help.